# Why doesn't this simulation work in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

I have been trying to simulate a frequency converter circuit consisting of a rectifier and an SPWM generator that control an H-bridge through the IR2112 driver. Everything works separately, but when I integrate them into the same project, simulation issues arise, reaching a point where it either fails to run or abruptly stops. I've attempted changing the Gmin, abstol, reltol, and even the cshunt, but nothing yields results.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are the diodes and MOSFETs using default models?

Comment: Where does the top power rail of the MOSFETs connect to i.e. what voltage is it?

Comment: The picture is too small resolution, upscale it please

Comment: If you could copy/paste the contents of your `.asc` file, we can attempt to run it ourselves.  In the meantime here are several things to try.  (1) Right-click and select actual part numbers for your diodes and MOSFETs. (2) Try using `UniversalOpamp2` instead of the `LM324` in all instances (you should also tell us where you got the LM324 model from). (3) Include `10m` series resistors for VCC and VEE. (4) Add a load to the output of your bridge rectifier. (5) Increase cshunt to `1e-12`.

Comment: why are VDD and VSS unconnected on the gate drivers?